# Is there a way to use the map() function to automate a pairwise.wilcoxon.test analysis for every column in R?

Tags: r, automation, analysis, pairwise

I'm pretty new at R, so I would love all the help that I can get!
I have a dataframe with 652 columns, where the first column has 3 factors, and the rest of the columns are the proteins and the number of proteins seen per factor. Here is what it looks like.

| Participant | C3 | FBN1 | TTN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AD | 6.0 | 1.1 | 4.2 |
| AD | 3.5 | 3.5 | 5.1 |
| AD | 7.0 | 2.3 | 9.0 |
| PD | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3.5 |
| PD | 2.0 | 8.4 | 2.4 |
| PD | 6.8 | 8.1 | 6.0 |
| PD | 3.5 | 3.7 | 5.7 |
| Control | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| Control | 9.1 | 1.0 | 7.3 |
| Control | 8.1 | 7.3 | 4.0 |
| Control | 5.0 | 8.2 | 2.1 |

So far, I have tried this code, but I get an error.

```
data <- read_excel('file.xlsx')
library(tidyverse)
WT_df <- data %>% select(c(2:652))
WT_data <- map_dbl(WT_df, ~ pairwise.wilcox.test(.x ~ data$Participant,
                           WT_df, p.adjust.method="fdr", paired=TRUE))


Error in if (length(ans) == 0L || as.character(ans[[1L]])[1L] == "~") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example of my data:

```
structure(list(Participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("AD", 
"Control", "PD"), class = "factor"), C3 = c(6, 3.5, 4, 14, 8, 
6.5, 7, 6.5, 10.5, 5.5, 2, 6.5, 7.5, 2.5, 13.5, 13.5, 9, 4.5, 
5, 21.5), ALB = c(39, 37, 43, 42, 41.5, 40, 36.5, 39.5, 40.5, 
42.5, 38.5, 40, 42, 39, 44.5, 40.5, 41.5, 39.5, 41, 42.5), TTN = c(36.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FLNA = c(20.5, 
15.5, 21, 19, 20.5, 14, 15.5, 17.5, 19.5, 18.5, 22, 19, 17, 19.5, 
17, 21.5, 18.5, 19, 21.5, 15.5),row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The column names (proteins) might not be the same for the table I provided, but that's not important.

Comment: hey! please include the reproducible example of your data. you can use dput() function to get the data. you can give for instance the top 20 rows of your data: dput(dataframe_name[ 1:20,])

Comment: You removed the "participant ID" column with `select()`, than referenced this column inside your formula

Comment: I removed the participant column initially, because I thought the wilcoxon test could only take numerical, and not factors